# How to import Java class in ClojureScript?

Tags: java, clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, clojure-java-interop

I am using a ClojureScript browser REPL in SublimeText, and there are certain Java methods included:

```
(.toUpperCase "blub") --> "BLUB"
```

However, I'd like to use `.toBinaryString`, but `java.lang.Integer` is not included and I'm not sure how to import it. `(import %)` doesn't work no matter what format I use for `%`; it always throws:

> cannot read property "call" of undefined

My question is two parts; how can I see what Java libs are included in the REPL, and how do I use other libraries that aren't included?

Answer (score 3):

ClojureScript compiles to JavaScript, the `toUpperCase` method that you called comes from **JavaScript** `String` not Java's. The only time in ClojureScript that you could use Java is when you're writing a macro. But that is because macros are written in Clojure, not in ClojureScript.

[This](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure) is a list of the differences between Clojure and ClojureScript.

Comment: I've read that and several articles on cljs-js interop, but whenever I try to use a js library (prototype.js in this case for the toString function), I get an error. This is after including a :libs and :foreign-libs clause in my project.clj file and requiring it in the namespace. I don't understand it.

Comment: Please create another question about that problem, or search in stackoverflow. Your original question was about Java interop, no?